# python scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer: why ValueError when input is 2 single-character strings?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I am trying to run something like this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

test_text = ["q", "r"]

vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,
                       stop_words=None, 
                       lowercase=False) 
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(test_text)

print vect.get_feature_names()
```

But get a ValueError:

`ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words`

Does guidance exist on what limitations or constraints for the input are? I was not able to find anything on the [TfidfVectorizer doc page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). I tried to trace it, and got to the `_count_vocab` function, but I have trouble reading it. Also, when I change the strings to length 2 or more, code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the min_df parameter. When you set the value of min_df =0, it will work fine as it will not be bounded by the 'minimum threshold' which is currently set to 1 and each of your word also appears for once only.

Comment: `min_df =0` did not work. Returned the same error. Did it work for you? Please post your code that worked.

Comment: Yes ,it worked for me. And the code is same, I just changed the value of min_df to 0. You should update your libraries.